# Format labels in D3.js graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have created a bar chart in d3.js. However I am not able to format the Y-axis lables as per requirement. What I want to do is to add space between label texts. I have used tickFormat() but it is not able to achieve the same. Here is the part of code.

```
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y)
.tickSize(3)
.tickFormat(function(d, i) {
    return d +"    "+TOP_TEN_CHANNELS[i].views+""; //to create custom tick format
});
```

I need a space equal to four spaces between channel name and views but, I am getting single space. Check my [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/6vyBuR).

Comment: Since this is not directly related to D3 I removed the versions reference from the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the [white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) property. In your case:

```
.barY .tick text {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

Here is the updated plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/Stp7XoESdmjcsRxWbAFV?p=preview